# Creating CSV file with full Digit Format rather in String Format using Shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am creating a csv file from Hive Table using below shell script

```
hive -e "select * from pontis_analyst.sms_fact_agg_check order by effective_date_ge_prt desc" |sed  's/[\t]/,/g' | sed  's/sms_fact_agg_check.//g' > /mapr/runtime/tools/DataValidation/fact_agg_check/Output/SMS_Fact_Agg_Check_Report_${now}.csv
```

but the values in the csv file is getting populated as

```
2019-11-17,218684346,206183052,12501294,5.72,6.85803157E8,6.50372607E8,3.543055E7,5.17

2019-11-16,241711982,240579922,1132060,0.47,7.51192998E8,7.49462398E8,1730600.0,0.23
```

I want it as full values in digit format rather in '6.85803157E8'

How can I redirect my csv file to get the values inside those columns be '197930257.49' rather 1.98E+08

can anyone help me out here

Comment: look at `hive`documentation if there is not already some option to configure numerical and for output `.csv` files.

Answer (score 1):

`cast` them

```
select cast(6.50372607E8 as decimal(20,2)) as n

+------------+
|           n|
+------------+
|650372607.00|
+------------+

select cast(1.98E+08 as decimal) as n
+---------+
|        n|
+---------+
|198000000|
+---------+
```